# AppleScript to turn off the monitor if not in use for more than 15 mins

Tags: macos, automation, applescript

I would like to turn off monitor if not in use for more than 15 mins. I have this script below:

```js
tell application "System Events"
  set frontApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
  set mouseMoved to false
  repeat
    set currentPosition to get the mouse location
    if currentPosition is not equal to {-1, -1} then
      if currentPosition is not in {{0, 0}, {0, 1079}} then
        set mouseMoved to true
      end if
    end if
    if mouseMoved is false then
      tell application "System Preferences"
        activate
        set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
      end tell
      tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
        click button "Display" of tab group 1 of window 1
        delay 2
        click radio button "Turn off after: 15 min" of tab group 1 of window 1
      end tell
      keystroke "q" using {command down}
    end if
    delay 60
  end repeat
end tell
```

When I test it I am getting: Expected end of line but found class name.

I looked online for solutions but still no clue how to fix this. Any advices would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `System Events` doesn't have a `mouse location` property.

Answer (score 0):

Setting display to sleep after N minutes (when no any activity registered) is the job for the Power Management utility (pmset). I recommend to use following script as run-only, for security reasons.

```
displaySleepAfterMiunutes(15)

on displaySleepAfterMiunutes(sleepAfterMinutes)
    set thePassword to "*******" -- set your ADMIN password here
    set UserName to do shell script "echo $USER"
    do shell script "pmset displaysleep " & sleepAfterMinutes user name UserName password thePassword with administrator privileges
end displaySleepAfterMiunutes
```

Full safe approach:

```
do shell script "pmset displaysleep 15" with administrator privileges
```

Comment: Note that "run-only" just prevents the script source from being opened in the Script Editor - there isn’t really any security, as strings are _not_ obfuscated or encrypted, and can easily be viewed by a text/hex editor.